# Convert a large string to Dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I've a large string looking like this :

'1 Start Date  str_date B 10 C \n 2 Calculation notional   cal_nt C 10 0\n 3 Calculation RATE Today  cal_Rate_td C 9 R\n ....'

the issue is that I can't use one space or two to split my string because from Start date to str_date  theres 2spaces but in the next line there will be 3 for example and maybe the next line will have 1space to seperate ... this makes it very hard to create a correct DataFrame as I want, is there a way to this ? thanks

Comment: here `3 Calculation RATE Today cal_Rate_td C 9 R` you have 8 fields while in the rest 7 ?

Comment: Yes that's normal because my second field can have more than 2 words for example 3 like `Calculation RATE Today` @kederrac

Comment: so what is the pattern: index a number, first column title case words an then one word ?

Comment: Did you try splitting on \n and can you describe what you are looking to extract from this text

Comment: there's no pattern thats why its very hard to do because space between each field is completely arbitrary .... if I cant put it into dataframe at least I would love only to extract the part with _ in a list for example list=['str_date, cal_nt, cal_Rate_td']

Comment: @QuantumDreamer there's 6 fields this string on each line my goal is to put those fields into a table with 6 columns Field1: 1 Field2:  Start Date Field3:str_date Field4: B Field5: 10 Field6: C

Comment: @QuantumDreamer I just got another idea of how to split field 2 and field 3 all of them have max size of 34 characters so basiclly size of field 2 is 34 characters containing space and field 3 is the same 34 characters containing space do you think this can work using this pattern ?

Comment: @QuantumDreamer basically size of field 1 : Characters 3, Field 2 : Characters 34, Field 3 : Characters 34, , Field 4 : Characters 2, Field 5 : Characters 4, Field 6 : Characters 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get a list with all the words that have `_`  (as you requested in the comments) you could use a regular expression:

```
import re

s = '1 Start Date str_date B 10 C \n 2 Calculation notional cal_nt C 10 0\n 3 Calculation RATE Today cal_Rate_td C 9 R\n ....'

list(map(re.Match.group, re.finditer(r'\w+_.\w+', s)))
```

output:

```
['str_date', 'cal_nt', 'cal_Rate_td']
```

or you can use a list comprehension:

```
[e for e in s.split() if '_' in e]
```

output:

```
['str_date', 'cal_nt', 'cal_Rate_td']
```

---

to get a data frame from your string you could use the above information, the third field:

```
s = '1 Start Date str_date B 10 C \n 2 Calculation notional cal_nt C 10 0\n 3 Calculation RATE Today cal_Rate_td C 9 R\n'
third_fields = [e for e in s.split() if '_' in e]    

rows = []
for third_field, row in zip(third_fields, s.split('\n')): 
    current_row = []
    row = row.strip()
    first_field = re.search(r'\d+\b', row).group()
    current_row.append(first_field)
    # remove first field
    row = row[len(first_field):].strip()

    second_field, rest_of_fields = row.split(third_field)
    parsed_fields = [e.group() for e in re.finditer(r'\b[\w\d]+\b', rest_of_fields)]
    current_row.extend([second_field, third_field, *parsed_fields])

    rows.append(current_row)


pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Is there another way please?

Comment: I just got another idea of how to split field 2 and field 3 all of them have max size of 34 characters so basiclly size of field 2 is  34 characters containing space and field 3 is the same 34 characters containing space do you think this can work using this pattern ?

Comment: basically size of field 1 : Characters 3, Field 2 : Characters 34, Field 3 : Characters 34, , Field 4 : Characters 2, Field 5 : Characters 4, Field 6 : Characters 2.

Comment: it was helpful thanks gave you upvote, wondering if you have any idea how to use size to split a string ?

Comment: @habdie you can check now my answer

Comment: Im getting an error here second_field, rest_of_fields = row.split(third_field) not enough values to unpack( 2expected, got 1) is it normal ?

Comment: Did you try with the string s?

Comment: I will give your answer upsolution :)

Comment: I figure out why I get an error, when the first field is two number for example 10, i get an error do you know how can i fix this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Like @kederrac answer, you can use regex to split them

```py
import re
s = "1 Start Date str_date  B  10   C "
l = re.compile("\s+").split(s.strip()) 
# output ['1', 'Start', 'Date', 'str_date', 'B', '10', 'C']
```

Comment: oh, sorry. I thought you was trying to split string. Can you provide some input and your expected output in your question?

Comment: I just got another idea of how to split field 2 and field 3 all of them have max size of 34 characters so basiclly size of field 2 is 34 characters containing space and field 3 is the same 34 characters containing space do you think this can work using this pattern ?

Comment: basically size of field 1 : Characters 3, Field 2 : Characters 34, Field 3 : Characters 34, , Field 4 : Characters 2, Field 5 : Characters 4, Field 6 : Characters 2.

Comment: Just to be clear, because 2nd field can contain more than 1 word, you unable to determine 3rd field.

Comment: field 2 can contain more than 1 word .. but size is 34character